# Unadded MKMapView renderInContext problems

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, rendering

I am trying to get an image out of a MKMapView to add as a "thumbnail" image to a UITableViewCell. The problem is that the image renders as a solid color and not as the correct map. I have added the MKMapView straight to my view simply for test purposes and it loads correctly.

Here is some code from cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
//create correct map thumbnail
    MKMapView *mapForThumbnail = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    mapForThumbnail.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    mapForThumbnail.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[coordinates.count];
    for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.count; i++){
        CLLocation *currentLocationCoords = [coordinates objectAtIndex:i];
        coords[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocationCoords.coordinate.latitude, currentLocationCoords.coordinate.longitude);

    }//end for

    MKPolyline *polylineForMapThumbnail = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordinates.count];
    [mapForThumbnail addOverlay:polylineForMapThumbnail];
    [mapForThumbnail setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([polylineForMapThumbnail boundingMapRect])];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100, 100), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [mapForThumbnail.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
    UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 cell.imageView.image = mapImage;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringForDetailLabel;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12.0f];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

Here is an image of whats happening:

[image: problem]